# Can Yeoman generators update existing files?

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

So just to give you some context, I'm trying to create a generator that will create some files (based on user input of course) *as well as* update some existing files in the project (like adding a new route for example).

Creating the files using `this.template` is no problem... the question is: is there any way to do this with Yeoman without having to read the file using Node and doing some fanciful find and replace?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Ok, so I found the answer to my question.

Addy Osmani showed me where to look in [this thread on twitter](https://twitter.com/remybach/status/386089572557676544), and then I later found [this link](http://paulfreeman.me.uk/development/process/how-i-came-to-love-yeoman-by-writing-my-own-generators) which shows exactly what I need.

The gist of it boils down to two functions : `readFileAsString` and `write`. Usage is as follows:

```js
var path = "/path/to/file.html",
    file = this.readFileAsString(path);

/* make modifications to the file string here */

this.write(path, file);
```

Edit: I've also blogged about this [on my blog](http://remy.bach.me.uk/blog/2013/10/updating-existing-files-with-yeoman/).

### EDIT 1

As mentionned in comments by Toilal :

> The `write` method doesn't exists anymore, and must be replaced by `writeFileFromString` (arguments are also reversed) – Toilal

### EDIT 2

And then, as mentionned in comments by ivoba:

> `this.writeFileFromString` & `this.readFileAsString` are deprecated, github.com/yeoman/html-wiring should be used by now, things change :) – ivoba

Comment: The write method doesn't exists anymore, and must be replaced by writeFileFromString (arguments are also reversed)

Comment: this.writeFileFromString & this.readFileAsString are deprecated, https://github.com/yeoman/html-wiring should be used by now, things change :)

Comment: Is there a way to perform this twice in one generator? Even if I put two of these using different `hooks` it only applies the second modification.

Comment: `html-wiring` is deprecated too.

Answer (score 24):

Yeoman also provides a more elegant way of fs operations using [mem-fs-editor](https://github.com/sboudrias/mem-fs-editor).

You can use `this.fs.copy`, passing a process function as an option to do any modifications to the content:

```js
this.fs.copy(path, newPath, {
    process: function(content) {

        /* Any modification goes here. Note that contents is a Buffer object */

        var regEx = new RegExp('old string', 'g');
        var newContent = content.toString().replace(regEx, 'new string');
        return newContent;
    }
});
```

This way you can also take advantage of `mem-fs-editor` features.

Comment: it is dangerous to use regEx to update a js file, Yeoman documentation discourages this, as stated for@Wtower

Comment: I agree. though it hasn't been mentioned in the question that the source file is a js file.

Answer (score 5):

In combination with @sepans' excellent answer, instead of using regular expressions, one can use some parser.

From Yeoman [documentation](https://yeoman.io/authoring/file-system.html#tip-update-existing-files-content):

> #### Tip: Update existing file's content
>
> Updating a pre-existing file is not always a simple task. The most reliable way to do so is to parse the file [AST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) and edit it. The main issue with this solution is that editing an AST can be verbose and a bit hard to grasp.
>
> Some popular AST parsers are:
>
> - [Cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) for parsing HTML.
> - [Esprima](https://github.com/ariya/esprima) for parsing JavaScript - you might be interested in [AST-Query](https://github.com/SBoudrias/ast-query) which provide a lower level API to edit Esprima syntax tree.
> - For JSON files, you can use the native [JSON object methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON).
>
> Parsing a code file with RegEx is perilous path, and before doing so, you should read this [CS anthropological answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#answer-1732454) and grasp the flaws of RegEx parsing. If you do choose to edit existing files using RegEx rather than AST tree, please be careful and provide complete unit tests. - Please please, don't break your users' code.

More specifically, when using esprima you will most probably require also some generator such as [escodegen](https://github.com/Constellation/escodegen) to generate js back.

```
var templatePath = this.destinationPath(...);
this.fs.copy(templatePath, templatePath, {
  process: function (content) {
    // here use the parser
    return ...
  }
});
```

Note that you can use the same path in `from`, `to` arguments in order to replace the existing file.

On the other hand, the downside of such parsers is that in some cases it may alter the original file way too much, and although safe, this is more intrusive.

Answer (score 1):

Use `var text = this.fs.read(filePath)` to read from a file and `this.fs.write(filePath, content)` to write to a file at location.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [mem-fs-editor](https://github.com/sboudrias/mem-fs-editor#appendfilepath-contents-options), and call the `fs.append(filepath, contents, [options])` method.

e.g.

```
this.fs.append(this.contextRoot + "/index.html", "  <p>Appended text</p>");
```

Comment: It is too complicate to edit `html` and it is not possible to use append to achieve valid result. I would suggest more simple file type for example here. For example `.gitignore`